# 12 balls are distributed in 5 numbered boxes. What is the probability that the first box end up with exactly 3 balls if (...)?

Tags: probability

12 balls are distributed in 5 numbered boxes. What is the probability that the first box end up with exactly 3 balls if?

a) The balls are distinguishable

b) The balls are identical

I tried using counting principles to obtain the cardinality of the sample space S and of the event E: "3 balls are in the first box". Assuming at least 1 ball in each box at the end of the experiment and the condition of equiprobability, I got:

card(S)=12!/7!

for card(E) I fixed the 3 in the first box and multiplied it by the remaining possibilities for each box (9 then 8,7, then 6). I expected the result of card(S)/card(E) would be the probability if the balls were identical but I got it wrong.

How can I approach that problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What difference does it make if the balls are distinguishable or not?  Presumably each ball goes into each box with equal probability, no?  If you meant some distribution other than that, you really need to spell it out explicitly.

Comment: Is each different combination equally likely in the two situations?  Because if the balls are labeled, a combination such as $(4~4~4~4~0)$ is more likely than $(12~0~0~0~0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you attach labels to the balls, so that the balls are distinguishable.  So, you run a simulation $~10,000~$ times, to see how often exactly $~3~$ balls (no more and no less) end up in box-1.

Then, you tear the labels off of the balls, so that now the balls are indistinguishable.  Then you re-run the simulation $~10,000~$ times.

You should expect roughly equivalent results.  That is, whether the balls are labeled or not will in no way affect how many balls end up in box-1.

Therefore, the probability that exactly $~3~$ balls end up in box-1 is the **same**, regardless of whether the balls are distinguishable or not.

Let the desired computation be represented by $$\frac{N}{D}. \tag1 $$

Then, you have a choice.  You can either assume that the balls are distinguishable, or assume that the balls are indistinguishable.  However, whichever assumption that you make, must be consistently applied when computing both $~N~$ and $~D~$ in (1) above.

---

The most convenient assumption is that the balls are distinguishable.  Then, assuming that the distribution of each ball into one of the boxes is independent of the distribution of any of the other balls, you have $~5~$ **equally likely** choices for each of the $~12~$ balls.

Therefore,

$$D = (5)^{12}.$$

To compute $~N,~$ first you have to determine which $~3~$ balls will be sent to box-1.  This can be done in $~\displaystyle \binom{12}{3}~$ ways.

So, reserve the factor of $~\displaystyle \binom{12}{3},~$ and then assume, without loss of generality that balls 1 through 3 (only) go to box-1.

Then, there are $~4~$ choices for each of the other balls.  So, the number of ways of distributing balls 4 through 12 is $~(4)^9.$

Therefore, $~\displaystyle N = \binom{12}{3} \times 4^9.$

Therefore, the probability is

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{\binom{12}{3} \times (4)^9}{(5)^{12}}.$$